# Different default sorting in pivot table in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I'm importing data from external source, and it usually goes like W1, W2, W3 .... W10, W11 and so on.
When I choose to make pivot table they get sorted like W1, W10, W11, W2 and so on.
Is there a way to make excel sort like it's listed in source?

Answer (score 1):

You have numbers sorted as text.

To prevent the problem, use e.g. `W00`, `W01`, and so on for two-digit numbering, or similar for three digits... ( W000, W001, W002, ...) - or remove the `W` altogether so that you have pure numbers, but make sure they're actually numbers - and not stored as text.